# Locked received coin

Tags: transactions

This is a picture of my reminato deposit history.
Hello,i received btc on my reminato wallet,the btc did not credit but shows in transaction status lockef[image]

Comment: Can you share the full txid or receiving address? That may help someone answer your question.